# Cross domain iframe position

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, position

I'm trying to find an easy way to get an external iframe's absolute position within the page.  What I'm looking for is something similar to the following:

```
$(window.parent.document).find("#iframe").position().top
```

but that works cross domain.  Is window.postMessage function the only/best way to solve this or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Only a few browsers support window.postMessage so hope you do not have to support older browsers.

Comment: Just looking to implement this on the iPad so only modern browsers need apply!